# React Native: update an Array inside an Object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i currently have an object and inside this object i have multiple objects and Arrays. I want replace an Array inside this object with a new Array, so i thought of making a copy of the entire object and simple replace the Array i wan to change with the updated Array. My problem is i couldnt complete my code, i have the idea of how to do it but cant execute it.

```
    setListings(listings=>
    listings.map(item =>{
      if(item.id === msg.id){

        //console.log(item)
        //console.log(item.Message)
        const newMessages = [msg,...item.Messages]
        //console.log(newMessages)
        return console.log([msg,...item.Messages],{...item}) // just for testing purpose i 
                                                                am returning a console log 
                                                                to see what it will get me. Not correct.
      }
      return item;
    })
    );
```

So basically listings is my state variable, here console.log(item) prints out the entire object, console.log(item.Messages) prints out the current Messages Array which i want to replace, console.log(newMessages) prints out the new Messages Array which i want to replace the current Messages array with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So basically what i want to achieve here is to add the msg object to the existing Messages Array.

Since lsitings is an Array of objects using the `.map` i can spread through each object and check if the id of that object is each to my `msg.id`. if that is true then i want to return a copy the that specific listing and edit the Messages Array within `[msg, ...item.Messages]` otherwise return the existing item.

```
  setListings(listings=> listings.map(item => {
    if(item.id === msg.id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        Messages: [msg, ...item.Messages]
      }
    }
    return item;
  }));

});
```

Comment: Hi, please add some comments that explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
cartItem.map((food,index)=> {
            if(food.food_id == newFoodItem.food_id && food.id == newFoodItem.id){
              const AllFoodData = cartItem
              AllFoodData[index] = newFoodItem
              AsyncStorage.setItem('@Add_cart_Item', JSON.stringify(AllFoodData))
                .then(() => {})
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
                ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset('Cart Replace Successfully',ToastAndroid.LONG,ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,25,50 )
            }
          })
```

Comment: I think this will help you to replace single object in a array..

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, i am not trying to replace a single object in a array. I am either trying to add a new object to my Messages Array, or creating a new Array and replacing the old one with the new one.